# Are there names for $A_n$, $Z_n$ and $B_n$ in a chain complex?

Tags: terminology, homological-algebra

I mean similar name like *$n$-th homology group*. If there would be, say "*$n$-th component*" for $A_n$, "*The cycles of $A_n$*" for $Z_n$, and "*The boundaries of $A_n$*" for $B_n$ than I could say that "Any cycle and boundary preserving homomorphism between the components of two chain complexes induces a homomorphism between the corresponding homology groups". What is the correct terminology for this?

Answer (score 1):

If $C=(C_p)$ is a (co)cochain complex then elements in $C_p$ are usually called $p$-(co)chains.

Comment: Then $C_p$ itself is the $p$-th (co)chain space, isn't it? And similarly, $Z_p$ and $B_p$ are the $p$-th (co)cycle space and $p$-th (co)boundary space.

Comment: @mma Because they needn't be spaces (in whatever usage of the word you can think of) you can just call them the sets or collection of $p$-(co)chains.

Comment: But they are modules, aren't they? It has no sense to talk about homomorphisms between sets, or collections. OK, don't call them spaces, But what? (Co)chain module, (co)cycle module and (co)boundary module?

Comment: Modules are sets before being modules.